# How to convert a neg mixed number to improper fraction?

Tags: java, fractions

I have this method in my fraction class,

```
public void toImproper() {
    if (denom == 0) {

        denom = 1;
    }
    num = (denom * coeff) + num;
    coeff = 0;

}
```

I have been using some test cases in this fraction calculator I am making such as -1_1/2 * 2 but I am getting 1 as my answer (next paragraph clears this up).

At first I put it into improper form right as I get the input, but making it improper AGAIN is giving me some problems. It is making -1_1/2 = -1/2 because of my method. -1_1/2 in improper form should be -3/2 but my method give -1/2. This is because it multiplies the coefficient by the denominator then adds the numerator. So for the numerator you get (-1 * 2) + 1. How can I fix this? I thought of using Math.abs(); but then it makes all negatives positive.

Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to tell what you're trying to do.  What is the input, and what output do you expect?  What is `coeff`?  What is `num` and where are you initializing it?

Comment: Sorry, coeff is the whole number in my mixed fraction (the -1), num = numerator and it is initialized earlier in the program. My expected is -3/2 but I am getting -1/2.

Comment: OK, that helps clarify.  For the record, I do not think "coefficient" is the right term for the whole-number part, which is part of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is basically that if you input -1 1/2 (`coeff=-1`, `num=1`, `denom=2`), the program treats this as (-1) + (1/2).  That is, it's interpreting the 1/2 part as positive, like it normally would.  You need to do something special to fool the program into thinking 1/2 *really* means -1/2 in this case.

Inserting this before the assignment to `num` is one way to fool the program:

```
if (coeff < 0) {
    num = -num;
}
```